# How to keep a consistent theme or page layout?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm new to SharePoint Online.

I created a new site collection named "company-my" first. This is how the home page looks like

[image]

After this, I added one more page for about section "About Us". And this is what was I got

**About Us** :
[image]

**Home** :
[image]

The theme and colours have slightly changed. I don't want that to happen. I want all of my pages to have a consistent theme. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The About us page that you have created is a Modern Site page which is latest in SharePoint Online.

I am sure you have created the page by hitting on setting icon and then clicking on "Add a Page" link.

In order to create a classic page in modern site collection you have to follow below steps:

1. Open Site Content Page
2. Then click on Site Pages Library
3. Then click on "New"
4. Then click on "Wiki Page" instead of site page.

And in this way you can create your classic page.

In order to read in detail, please refer to [this wonderful article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-bypass-the-new-modern-team-site-page-experience/).

Let me know if you still have any confusion.

Comment: Before trying out your answer, I want to delete the current "About Us" page. How can I do it? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Go to "site content", and then "site page" library there you will find the page with Name which you have given and from there you can delete that.

Comment: One more question similar to this. If I want to do the same thing while adding a subsite, how can I do it? It's because the theme and colours changed when I created a new subsite for a site. I just want all the sites/pages/subsites to be part of a consistent theme. And it'd be even better if I have the ability to change the theme of all OR any one of the sites as per my choice.

Comment: While creating a new subsite you will always have 2 options. 1. Team site and another one as 2. Team Site (Classic Experience). Select "Team Site (Classic Experience) for creating subsite.